# Mixing 32bit and 64bit managed assemblies

Tags: .net

All,

I have a .NET managed application which runs in 32bit machines.
I am fine with compiling it to 64bit and port it on a 64bit machine.
However I depend on some 3rd party DLLs which are 32 bit assemblies.
Can I mix 64bit and 32bit assemblies together executing on a 64bit machine?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not if they are running in the same process.

A process on the OS cannot load assemblies of different "bit-ness". Once chosen, all assemblies have to conform. You will get a `BadImageFormatException` usually if you attempt to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process or vice versa.

Three options:

1. Get 64-bit versions of the problem DLLs (ideal).
2. Run exclusively in 32-bit all the time (usually the chosen path).
3. Run the problem DLLs in another process and use something like IPC to talk across the process boundary (extreme, but I've had to do this once).

There is nothing inherently wrong with running in 32-bit on a 64-bit OS, don't fall into the trap of thinking it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, no.

I developed a system which relied on 32-bit iSeries COM libraries which I had no control over.  Ran into problems, and fixed them by compiling a 32-bit version of the application.

Just ensure that instead of targeting Any CPU, you set Visual Studio to compile to x86.

Also be aware that your generated DLLs and executables will be in a slightly different place.

e.g.

bin\x86\Debug

instead of

bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget if you run 32 bit it *might* not be slower but you may run out of memory.